# Book about a boy who manages to take down an entire alien army with his friends

Tags: story-identification, aliens

There was a book that I'd read a while back but can't for the life of me remember the name of.  There was a boy who went to space during an alien war and managed to defeat the aliens by taking out their leader.

The boy's name is a blank, however, he was odd, as in not normal.  He was the third child and the book started with some sort of medical procedure.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*[Ender's Game](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2004)* by Orson Scott Card?

The boy's name was Andrew Wiggin, but was nicknamed "Ender". He was a third child (two older siblings called Valentine and Peter), and at the start of the book has a medical procedure to remove a monitoring device. He controlled a fleet of spaceships via an instantaneous communication device, and defeated the aliens, the "formics" or "buggers", by destroying their homeworld.

A fuller summary is available at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game).

Comment: @charlesjohns12 It was made into a feature film too.

Comment: If you liked the book there is at least one follow-up of Ender as an adult. Like all of OSC's books, readable and well-plotted, but very dark and uncomfortable in places.

Comment: Note that the "third child" thing was relevant to the setting, as there was a two-child policy in place due to overpopulation. Andrew's parents got an exemtion. @RedSonja I'm on follow-up number two as we speak: There is Speaker for the Dead, and Xenocide. Allegedly, these were the books OSC really wanted to write, and Ender's Game was necessary for setup, but maybe take that with a grain of salt.

Comment: Children of the Mind is the 4th novel in the main Ender arc.  Beyond that OSC's put out a large number of prequel and parallel stories in the same universe.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game_(novel_series)#Novels_in_the_series

Comment: The "Shadow" books are, IMHO, much better written than the "Speaker" books. Of course OSC had about 30 years more experience as a writer when he took up Ender's Shadow, and it shows.